# How to retrieve Firebase data into TableView android? Should I use a RecycleView or that works for a list only?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-tablelayout

I'm trying to retrieve content form Firebase and place it on a TableLayout Android. Normal queries and event listeners or Firebase UI?

I'm new to both Android and Firebase so your help would be the most appreciated... thanks in advance

---

Comment: If you are interested, **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849)** is how you can retrieve data from a Firebase Realtime database and display it in a `RecyclerView` using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.

Comment: but the RecyclerView doesn't allow a onItemClickListener:< -my table contains clickable images, you click on one of it to access another activity so clicking and listing is rather important

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `RecyclerView`and set its layout by `RecylcerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager)`. The layoutManager can be defined as a `LinearLayoutManager` which supports displaying a list in a linear fashion. But you can also utilize a `GridLayoutManager`, which probably comes closest to a `TableLayout`. More information on the LayoutManager can be found in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html).

For read/write methods in Firebase a good explanation is given [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write). It describes the most common methods.

Comment: but the RecyclerView doesn't allow a onItemClickListener:< -my table contains clickable images, you click on one of it to access another activity so clicking and listing is rather important –

Comment: You can initialize ClickListeners for the RecyclerView and for single items in a RecyclerView. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick/26196831#26196831